# WSL + anchor: ERROR "admin.rpc does not exist"

Tags: anchor, wsl

I'm trying to run a Solana App through WSL.

When running "anchor localnet" to test the app I get the following error:
"Unable to connect to validator: Client error: .anchor/test-ledger/admin.rpc does not exist"

This error is common when using solana-test-validator on WSL, in that case the solution is simply to use "solana-test-validator" in the root folder (by doing so, the command will easily find admin.rpc that is also located in a subfolder under root).

However the app I'm trying to run is located in a completely different directory, when trying to run "anchor localnet" or "solana-test-validator" in that folder it will not work.

How to I tell anchor localnet where to find the admin.rpc file?
I haven't found any solution online.